# When loading player data any number above around 400 gets cut down to exactly 319

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to save and load basic player data in Unity, but whenever I load the game everything loads properly except anything with a value stored that is a greater than 400, gets reduced to 319. For example, if I have saved 200 coins, it will load 200 coins, but if I have 500 coins, it will load 319 coins.

This is the code I use to save:

```
public static void save() {
    Debug.Log("Saving Player Data");

    //Convert Player Data to String
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bf.Serialize(ms, playerData);
    byte[] newData = ms.ToArray();
    string newDataString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(newData);

    FileStream file = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerData.aaa");
    bf.Serialize(file, newDataString);
    file.Close();
}
```

And here is the code I use to load:

```
public static void load() {
    playerData = new PlayerData();
    if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerData.aaa")) {
        try {
            Debug.Log("Loading Player Data");

            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream file = File.Open(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerData.aaa", FileMode.Open);
            string dataString = bf.Deserialize(file).ToString();
            file.Close();

            //Convert String to Player Data
            byte[] playerDataBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataString);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ms.Write(playerDataBytes, 0, playerDataBytes.Length);
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            playerData = (PlayerData)bf.Deserialize(ms);
        } catch(Exception) {
            Debug.Log("Messed Up Player Log: Creating New");
            File.Delete(Application.persistentDataPath + "/playerData.aaa");
            save();
        }
    } else {
        Debug.Log("Player Data does not exist. Creating new and saving it");
        save();
    }
}
```

playerData is the object that contains the playerData. It is serializable.

Here is the code for the playerData:

```
using System.IO;

[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerData{
    public bool tutorialComplete = false;

    public ArtStyle artPrefs = ArtStyle.ORIGINAL;

    public int coins = 0;

    public ShopItem brightTexturePack = new ShopItem("Bright", 5);
    public ShopItem neonTexturePack = new ShopItem("Neon", 50);
    public ShopItem paperTexturePack = new ShopItem("Paper", 500);

    public ShopItem getShopItem(string itemName) {
        switch(itemName) {
            case "BRIGHT":
                return brightTexturePack;
            case "NEON":
                return neonTexturePack;
            case "PAPER":
                return paperTexturePack;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class ShopItem {
    public int price;
    public string name;
    public bool isBought = false;

    public ShopItem(string name, int price) {
        this.price = price;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The only places I have seen the issue occur is in the variable coins and the price of the Neon Texture Pack, because they are the only variables that normally reach above 400.

I have been trying to figure out what the issue is for really long, but the whole problem just doesn't make sense to me at all. It always changes any number greater than 400 stored in any of the variables in the playerData to 319.

Comment: What does `playerData` look like?

Comment: Also, why do you in `save` appear to serialize your `playerData` to a byte array, then convert it to a string, and then serialize the string? That makes no sense.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more like how is playerData created? Why aren't you passing it as a parameter to the save function?

I'm going to throw out a guess and assume you are making everything static and its causing value to be overwritten.

Comment: There is nothing inherently wrong with the code you've posted (aside from the goofy double serialization I mentioned earlier which isn't need - but it does no harm), so your problem is somewhere else. Without seeing the code for `playerData` this question will be impossible to answer

Comment: I'll add the code for the playerData in the question, and the double serialization exists because originally the save and load functions included encryption and decryption, so I needed to convert to byte array and convert to string then encrypt string then serialize that encrypted string. When I was testing to figure out why this error was happening I removed the encryption stuff, but I didn't really change it to optimize the actual saving process without encryption.

Comment: Sam Marion I am making the playerData static, because there will always be only one playerData active at a time, and if it's static I can always access it from anywhere without creating an object. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If there's only ever one instance of PlayerData it should be fine, it was just a guess since there wasn't much to go on. Also the code you provided for PlayerData is not static? I would put some debug lines out before you searlize and see if the value of coins is what you expect. You need to narrow down where exactly its changing.

Comment: Also, use the debugger! Its very useful, step through the code and check the values of coins in areas you think it could be changed. This will make it easy to figure out where its being changed and how to fix it.

Comment: My game loads by creating a static object PlayerData playerData and then setting it equal to the deserialized data. Whenever I need to access coins for example, I do playerData.coins. I guess just making the class static would be better though

Comment: Okay, I tried doing some more debugging to locate where coins changes, but whats happening is coins does not change at all during gameplay. While I am playing I can get coins all the way up to a thousand and the value will constantly be a thousand, but when I close the game and restart it the value of coins will be 319 if it is greater than 400, and the value its supposed to be. The value of coins doesn't seem to actually ever change, it just seems to read the value incorrectly when playerData is loaded at the start of the game

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is `BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();` combined with `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(newData);` you can't call GetString on arbitrary data you are getting from your serialize call, you will see lost data like you are getting.

Use the [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) class built in to unity to turn your class in to a string instead of using BinaryFormatter + GetString

Answer (score 7):

When you are serialising your object, the `int` field is being serialised - a value of 400 (`0x0190` in hexadecimal) gets serialised into two bytes: `0x01` and `0x90`.

However, you're using an ASCII encoding and the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38b953c8(v=vs.110).aspx) for `ASCII.GetString` states:

> ASCIIEncoding does not provide error detection. Any byte greater than hexadecimal 0x7F is decoded as the Unicode question mark ("?").

The Unicode question mark has a value of `0x3F` - your original bytes of `0x01` and `0x90` actually get saved as `0x01` and `0x3F`.

Guess what the hex number `0x013F` is in decimal?

It's 319.

Because of your use of `ASCII.GetString` any number higher than 383 (`0x017F`) will always get serialised to 319.

Actually, I've just realised that any number with a low order byte value of greater than `0x7F` will be changed using your serialisation, so trying to save just 128 coins will result in your load method returning a value of 63 coins.

Look into other ways of persisting your objects.

Comment: Thanks! That explanation makes everything make so much more sense. I probably should have done more research, before doing this.

Comment: @Bhaskar - I had to debug your code and then spotted the difference in the binary arrays for saving and loading. This was a real headscratcher until I spotted it!